# Free XML Forms Designer for XML data

Tags: xml, winforms, forms, data-capture

I'm looking for a small and cheap (very) application that will let the user design a simple form to capture data to XML. The XML is very simple and will be overwritten with every capture, i.e. not written in a record in an XML 'database'. I can do it myself too easily with  Winforms but my friend is looking for a definite desktop, not online, application to generate the forms, and Visual Studio is just too expensive.

Comment: How about Google Forms? https://support.google.com/drive/answer/87809?hl=en

Comment: @leonm There is no option to store captured values anywhere but a Google spreadsheet or CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Altova Authentic](http://www.altova.com/authentic.html). They even have a community (free) version.